# X-axis to start from 0

Tags: c#, charts

I know this question has been asked before quite a few times, but no one seems to have come up with a solution (Not that I could find at least).

So, I have a chart for my application and I've added values

```
chart1.Series["Life"].Points.AddY(1);
chart1.Series["Life"].Points.AddY(30);
chart1.Series["Life"].Points.AddY(20);
chart1.Series["Life"].Points.AddY(50);
```

for which I get a chart like 
[image]

Now this is very displeasing to the eye first of all because the X needs to start from the origin.
So, question 1 - Why is it starting from 1?
Question 2 - How do I solve this?
This is the first time I am making a chart in c# so this might sound like a trivial dilemma.

Also, like I mentioned, I did my research and I found that I should do something like

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;    //made this -1
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Crossing = 0;   //and this too to -1
```

This didn't work so I decided to play a little with the minimum and crossing by giving them -1. Didn't work. The graph not only moved, but it still starts from 1. HOW?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Points.AddXY` method to specify the X coordinate too. To make sure that the line starts from the origin prepend data points with `(0, 0)`:

```
var series = chart1.Series["Life"];
series.Points.AddXY(0, 0);
series.Points.AddXY(1, 1);
series.Points.AddXY(2, 30);
series.Points.AddXY(3, 20);
series.Points.AddXY(4, 50);
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want your chart X-axis to start at 1?
why not use:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
```

?

or you want your points to start at 0? why not use :

```
chart1.ChartAreas["Life"].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
chart1.Series["Life"].Points.AddXY(0,1);
```

?